# Directional derivatives of homogeneous functions - Proof Correction

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Let $f$ be a homogenous function of degree $k$ differentiable away from the origin. Show that for any unit vector $u$ the directional derivative is homogeneous of degree $k-1$.

**(Incorrect) Proof**
Let $u$ be given. Since $f$ is differentiable, $\partial_uf(x)$ exists.

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\partial_uf(\lambda x) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \cfrac{f(\lambda x + uh) - f(\lambda x)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \cfrac{f(\lambda (x + \cfrac{h}{\lambda}u) - f(\lambda x)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \cfrac{\lambda^k\big[f(x + \cfrac{h}{\lambda}u) - f(x)\big ]}{h} \\
&= \lambda^k \partial_uf(x)
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You went wrong at the last step. To recognize the limit as the directional derivative, you need $h/\lambda$ in the denominator, and to get that you "borrow" one power of $\lambda$ from the $\lambda^k$. (Once you have $h/\lambda$ in the denominator, you do the standard thing of substituting $k=h/\lambda$ and noting that $h\to 0$ if and only if $k\to 0$.)